# Lua segfault when loading dll

Tags: c, dll, lua

I'm trying to make a c extension dll for lua. I have this `csin.c`:

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <math.h>

static int l_sin(lua_State *L) {
    double d = lua_tonumber(L, 1);
    lua_pushnumber(L, sin(d));
    return 1;
}

int luaopen_csin(lua_State *L) {
    lua_register(L, "csin", l_sin);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling it with `gcc -Wall -shared -Ilua-5.3.3/include -Llua-5.3.3/lib csin.c -o csin.dll -llua`. The include dir just has the `.h` files from the Lua 5.3.3 src download and the lib dir has `liblua.a` which I compiled with `make generic`. It compiles without error, but when I try to use it in a Lua script, it just gives a `Segmentation Fault`.

Here is `lcsin.lua`:

```
require("csin")
print(csin(45))
```

I just run it with `lua lcsin.lua`, `lua` being a link to `lua32/lua53.exe`, which I think I got from Lua's binary downloads. I tried using the compiled `lua-5.3.3/src/lua.exe` too, but it says:

```
lua-5.3.3/src/lua: lcsin.lua:1: module 'csin' not found:
        no field package.preload['csin']
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/csin.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/csin/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/csin.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/csin/init.lua'
        no file './csin.lua'
        no file './csin/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/csin.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
        no file './csin.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        lcsin.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

I think that error is because the compiled one isn't looking for `.dll` files but `.so` files. I'm using cygwin. Windows/Linux inconsistencies have been a pain in the *** for a while now. I've tried example code online, and nothing works.

Comment: it did not segfault, did it?

Comment: It did segfault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is indeed with searching for `.so` files instead of `*.dll` files, it should be easy to fix by adding the appropriate pattern to `package.cpath`:

```
package.cpath = package.cpath..";./?.dll"
require("csin")
```

Assuming `csin.dll` is in the current folder, it should be able to find and load it.

Comment: It says `dynamic libraries not enabled; check your Lua installation`. I compiled `lua.exe` with `make mingw`.

Comment: You need to have Lua itself compiled with `MYCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_DLOPEN"` or have `_WIN32` defined, which will turn `LUA_DL_DLL` on. Check `luaconf.h` for details.